# Magento 2.4.2: how to add a custom attribute field

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, google-product-feeds

I need to add a custom attribute field named `google_product_category` in addition to those already existing for products. I tried doing it with Add attribute button, but ended up seeing a new field called attributes which has the field that I wanted to see as one of the existing attributes such as Manufacturer Part Number. Below is how the custom `google_product_category` looks at the bottom. That is not how I expected to see it. It should have been added just as one of all those field that you see at the top. Please let me know how to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Take the following steps to change the Attribute set's Group**

> 1. Go to Store > Products -> Attribute set and Select Attribute and move to "General" Group

[image]

Comment: Gohil, can you tell me how to remove the one I created?

Comment: Go to store -> products -> Attributes ..here search your Attribute..then select Attribute and delete it